# download counter with symfony

Tags: symfony, download, counter

Hi I wish to realize a download counter with symfony 3

in *web/.htaccess* I have :

```
RewriteRule ^/up/(.*).(jpg|zip|pdf)$ /download/counter/$1/$2 [R,L]
```

in my controller AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php I have :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/download/counter/{filename}/{ext}", name="downloadcounterfile")
     */



    public function downloadcounterfileAction(Request $request)
    {
 ....
}
```

But the function "downloadcounterfileAction" is never executed

Comment: *But the function "downloadcounterfileAction" is never executed* - you probably have other RewriteRules that serve existing files directly without rewriting them to your front controller. Atleast the default Symfony `.htaccess` has such rules.

Comment: thank you for the proposals. finally I found an effective solution: awstats !!! it gives detailed download statistics. I use it for my site: sendeyo.com which is dedicated to file hosting ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to a URL `/up/xyz.jpg` and actually end up at `/download/counter/xyz/jpg` you could just add a new action/endpoint `/up/{filename}`, and parse the filename, splitting up the basename from extention, checking them to ensure they are in the three valid extensions.

It is also possible to have three more alias routes to the `/up/` path prefix:

```
/**
 * @Route("/download/counter/{filename}/{ext}", name="downloadcounterfile")
 * @Route("/up/{filename}.jpg", defaults={"ext"="jpg"})
 * @Route("/up/{filename}.pdf", defaults={"ext"="pdf"})
 * @Route("/up/{filename}.zip", defaults={"ext"="zip"})
 */
public function downloadcounterfileAction(Request $request, $filename, $ext)
{
    echo "filename:$filename, ext:$ext\n";die;
}
```

Given the above Route-block and method, going to the URL: `/up/fred.zip` shows

```
filename:fred, ext:zip
```

`/download/counter/fred/zip` produces the same result with it included in the listed @Routes.

Although it will fail if there is a full-stop in the filename - `No route found for "GET /up/fr.ed.zip"`.

Comment: thank you for the proposals. finally I found an effective solution: awstats !!! it gives detailed download statistics. I use it for my site: sendeyo.com which is dedicated to file hosting